# парадокс защиты кода

Tags: php

скачал плагин wysiwyg там добавляются img и другие html коды но проблема в том что так же и хакеры могут вводит какието sql запросы как исправить?

прогблема заключается в том что если я включю перепреобразование в html символы, то html коды не работают а если не вставляю преоброзавание то могут хакеры что то сделать..

вот код добавления новостей:

```
<?
include "bd.php";

$id = $_POST['id'];

$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'"); 
$myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$post = $_POST['post'];
if($_POST){
    $date = date("d.m.Y H:i");


    $result2 = mysqli_query ($db, "INSERT INTO wall_post (user_id,date,post) VALUES('$id','$date','$post')") or exit(mysqli_error($db));
    if ($result2){
        echo "<html><head><meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=page?id=$id'></head></html>";
    }
}
else{
    echo "<html><head><meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=fail_try?id=8'></head></html>";
}
?>
```

а вот код вывода:

```
<?
session_start();
include "bd.php";

$id = $_GET['id'];

$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM wall_post WHERE user_id='$id' ORDER BY id DESC");

$result2 = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'");
$myrow2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $post_id = $row['id'];
    $md5_id = md5(md5(md5(md5($id))));
    echo "
        <div class='profile_post'>
            <p>
                <a href='page?id=$id'><img class='avatar' src='$myrow2[avatar]' align='left'></a>
                <a href='page?id=$id' class='page_href'>$myrow2[lastname] $myrow2[firstname]</a><br>
                <font color='gray' size='2'>$row[date]</font>
                <div class='delete_news'><a href='delete_post?post_id=$post_id&hash=$md5_id&id=$id'></a></div>
            </p>
            <p>$row[post]</p>
        </div>
    ";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Лучше использовать [PDO](https://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/) и проблемы с SQL-инъекцией отпадут. А для полного контроля в вашем случае используйте

```
$input_text = strip_tags($text_input, '<p>'); // разрешает только тег <p>
$input_text = htmlspecialchars($input_text);
```

Подробнее о фильтрации почитайте [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/143035/)

P.S. проверьте `<p onclick="alert('XSS-атака удалась')">проверить XSS (кликните)</p>`

Answer (score -1):

Давайте поговорим о двух векторах возможных атак.
Первый - sql инъекция. Это когда хакер влезает в запрос к базе данных, и заставляет выполнить свой код.

Защита - в случае с MySQL - все параметры пропустить через функцию `mysql_real_escape_string()`.
Очень редко хакер может внедрить свои данные, чаще всего это вектор для кражи данных из базы данных.

Второй вектор - `javascript injection(xss)`. Защита - если вы знаете, что в данной переменной php НЕ предполагается HTML кода - пропустите ее через функцию `htmlspecialchars()`.

Вообще, хорошее решение использовать для защиты от подобных атак шаблонизатор вроде **Twig**, где все это есть из коробки.

P.S: Пишу с телефона, потому прежде чем использовать имена функций указанных мной загуглите синтаксис на всякий случай...

Comment: А функция mysql_real_escape_string() нужно использовать при вводе данных или выводе?

Comment: При вводе, потому что данные будут записаны в БД и если там есть инъекция, то она воспроизведется. При выводе на страницу очищать переменную на mysql_real_escape_string() смысла нет, т.к. она грузится из БД

Comment: @BedOmar ни то ни другое. Эту функцию вообще использовать не нужно, тем более так как написано в этом ответе. Инъекция будет гарантирована

Comment: @Ипатьев, удивите, почему не надо?

Comment: Просто потому что она не предназначена для защиты от каких бы то ни было инъекций. У нее в названии нет ни одного слова, похожего на "защита", "инъекция" и им подобных. Это заставляет задуматься.

Comment: @Ипатьев, сомнительная логика. Она экранирует спец символы строки, что собственно и дает первый минимум для защиты инъекций. Или..?

Comment: Вот именно что *строки*. Что делает ответ вида "прогоняйте через нее все данные и будете в шоколаде" как минимум вредоносным. Если уж взялся отвечать, то так и писать - "для строк защиту знаю, а остальное - как боженька рассудит".

Comment: @Ипатьев, одно уточнение: мной написано параметры: а что еще кроме строк по вашему может прийти с клиента?

Comment: При чем здесь клиент? Мы говорим про SQL инъекцию, а не про клиент-инъекцию.